# Bash sed with greedy regex

Tags: bash

I have a GTF file (type of TSV) with the following structure:

```
ENST00000488147.1|ENSG00000227232.5|OTTHUMG00000000958.1|OTTHUMT00000002839.1|WASH7P-201|WASH7P|1351|unprocessed_pseudogene|    13511132.24 244.489 2.7098
ENST00000619216.1|ENSG00000278267.1|-|-|MIR6859-1-201|MIR6859-1|68|miRNA|   68  26.127  0   0
ENST00000473358.1|ENSG00000243485.5|OTTHUMG00000000959.2|OTTHUMT00000002840.1|MIR1302-2HG-202|MIR1302-2HG|712|lncRNA|   712 493.243 0   0
```

I would like to remove all the names from the first column but the first, as separated by the "|". For example, the first line should be:

```
ENST00000488147.1    13511132.24 244.489 2.7098
```

My idea is to replace everything from first "|" to the first "\t" with "\t", but sed is failing me. This command makes no changes:

```
sed 's/|*\t/\t/' test.tsv
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this completely?

Comment: `\t` isn't compatible with *either* POSIX BRE or ERE regex syntax specifications, and counting on `|` to be interpreted as literal rather than an "or" / branching operator makes your code fragile (means it would fail if interpreted as ERE).

Comment: Also, even if a `|` is literal, `|*anything` would mean "zero-or-more pipes, followed by anything"; the `*` only matches zero-or-more of the specific thing it follows; it doesn't match "anything", as it would in a fnmatch/glob-style patterns as opposed to a regex.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wrt *means it would fail if interpreted as ERE* Do you know any implementation that does so?

Comment: If given the optional `-r` argument, many implementations will -- meaning the code can't be combined with other, ERE-specific practices.

Comment: Almost all. Without -r, it's not a problem. I didn't know POSIX sed didn't recognize `\t` though, thanks for that info, but one could use `\009` instead, right?

Comment: `\9` is defined by the POSIX regex spec as a backreference. I don't know that it has any other meaning, though the [relevant spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06) is rather dense and I don't know it backwards-and-forwards.

Comment: @oguzismail Re: `\009`, by my reading that's undefined behavior, so it's *legal* for a platform to treat it as a character ordinal, but not *required*.

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't know POSIX was this much restrictive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
sed -re $'s@[|][^\t]*\t@\t@g'
```

- Using `$'...'` is a ksh/bash syntax extension that makes `$'\t'` be expanded to a literal tab by the shell, instead of assuming that you have a `sed` that (without reference to the standard) treats `\t` sequences as if they were tabs.
- `sed -r` puts `sed` in POSIX ERE mode, vs BRE mode.
- Using `[|]` matches only the literal `|` character, regardless of which regex syntax variant is in use.
- Using `[^\t]*` matches zero-or-more *things that are not tabs*, whereas `.*` would match things that *are* tabs, which wouldn't result in the desired output.

---

In context, as testable code:

```
write_line() {
  printf '%s\t' "$@" && printf '\n';
}
generate_input() {
  write_line 'ENST00000488147.1|ENSG00000227232.5|OTTHUMG00000000958.1|OTTHUMT00000002839.1|WASH7P-201|WASH7P|1351|unprocessed_pseudogene|' 13511132.24 244.489 2.7098
  write_line 'ENST00000619216.1|ENSG00000278267.1|-|-|MIR6859-1-201|MIR6859-1|68|miRNA|'    68  26.127  0   0
  write_line 'ENST00000473358.1|ENSG00000243485.5|OTTHUMG00000000959.2|OTTHUMT00000002840.1|MIR1302-2HG-202|MIR1302-2HG|712|lncRNA|'    712 493.243 0   0
}
generate_input | sed -re $'s@[|][^\t]*\t@\t@g'
```

...produces [as output](https://ideone.com/6tmkqz):

```
ENST00000488147.1   13511132.24 244.489 2.7098  
ENST00000619216.1   68  26.127  0   0   
ENST00000473358.1   712 493.243 0   0
```

Comment: You are simply fantastic!